# dynamically allocating an int array inside a structure

Tags: c, malloc

I'm trying to dynamically create an array of ints for grades that are inside of a structure but I have a small syntax error. Here is my code:

```
typedef struct          
{
    int Stud_ID;
    int class_ID;
    int* Grades;
    int Grade_Cap;
    int Count;
    float Average;
}enrollment;

typedef struct 
{
    int Enrollment_Count;
    int Enrollment_Cap;
    enrollment *enrollment_list;
}enrollments;

void add_grade_space(enrollments *enroll)
{
    enroll->enrollment_list[enroll->Enrollment_Count].Grade_Cap =   malloc(sizeof(int)*2);
}
```

The error I get says: assignment makes integer from pointer without cast.

Comment: Member `Grade_Cap` is an `int`. What exactly is your intent?

Comment: Did you mean to use `....Grades = malloc(sizeof(int)*2;`?

Comment: @RSahu Maybe yes , it must be an typo .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
enroll->enrollment_list[enroll->Enrollment_Count].Grade_Cap =   malloc(sizeof(int)*2);
```

You are trying to allocate memory to `Grade_Cap` which is not a pointer . It is an integer variable .You need to declare it as `int *` to allocate memory if you want to.

Comment: @ColinO  You want to allocate to `Grades` or to `Grade_Cap` ?

Comment: no I should have put enroll->enrollment_list[enroll->Enrollment_Count].Grades instead of Grade_Cap

Comment: @ColinO  Yeah , so it was an typo .